# Android application crashes while scrolling custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, crash

When i test my application on AVD , the list view works correctly without crashing, but when i use my smartphone (GALAXY S3) it crashes while scrolling to the bottom (whitout make error message )

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercice_item_ex, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exercice_by_m_nom);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exercice_by_m_image);
TextView other = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exercice_by_m_other);
TextView equipem = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.exercice_by_m_equi);

String title = web[position];
String oths = oth[position];
String equs = equ[position];

txtTitle.setText(title);
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
other.setText(oths);
equipem.setText(equs);

return rowView;
}
```

I set adapter with this code.

```
ExerciceAdapter adapter = new ExerciceAdapter(getActivity(), exearr, imagearr,otharr,equiarr);
            list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_fragment_exercice);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: And please also post your fragment_exercice_item_ex.xml layout file.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

@MM-BB it doesnt makes any error, it just minimize the application